# Building app with spring-boot + Cassandra, getting "Unable to load class 'com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.entity.naming.GetterStyle'"

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Facing isssue while integration with datastax with cassandra

gradle file :

```
plugins {
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.12.RELEASE'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.13.RELEASE'
   id 'java'
   id 'org.sonarqube' version '3.2.0'
}

group = 'in.demo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'
def javaDriverVersion ='4.14.1'

configurations {
   compileOnly {
      extendsFrom annotationProcessor
   }
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
   implementation ('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
   compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
   annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
   testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
   implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
      exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
      exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-core'
      exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-databind'
      exclude group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', module: 'jackson-annotations'
   }
   implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')
   implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
   runtimeOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
   // datastax driver
   implementation group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-core', version: javaDriverVersion
   implementation group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-query-builder', version: javaDriverVersion
   //implementation group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-runtime', version: javaDriverVersion
   implementation group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'native-protocol', version: '1.5.0'
   annotationProcessor group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-processor', version: javaDriverVersion
   //compileOnly group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-processor', version: '4.14.1'
   compileOnly group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-runtime', version: javaDriverVersion


   implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'
   annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
}
tasks.named('test') {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(defaultKeyspace = "quest_test")
public class TestTable {
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Dao;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Select;

@Dao
public interface TestTableDao {
    @Select
    TestTable findById();
}
```

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoFactory;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface TestTableMapper {
    @DaoFactory
    TestTableDao testTableDao();
}
```

getting error
Unable to load class 'com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.entity.naming.GetterStyle'.

i tried to interaction with different project also but still not able to solve issue
. for testing part i added library mappstruct which is generation code on compile time

Answer (score 2):

With drivers 4x+, you need to declare an annotation processor for the mappers code to be generated at build time.

Gradle file

```
dependencies {
   annotationProcessor group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-processor', version: javaDriverVersion
   compile group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-runtime', version: javaDriverVersion
}
```

- [Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/mapper/config/)
- Here [more code to work with Driver 4x](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x/tree/master/example-4x/src/main/java/com/datastax/samples)
- You might be interested in the [full-fledged Spring PetClinic](https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-reactive) application running with your technical stack.